# PHP/WP concatenation - string ends up in two parts

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'object', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo "<div class=\"item\"><a href=\"" . the_permalink() . "\">" . the_title() . "</a></div>";
endwhile;
```

This loop I have in WP is not echoing

```
<div class="item"><a href="#mylink">The name of my link</a></div>
```

but instead

```
#mylink The Name of my link
<div class="item"><a href=""></a></div>
```

Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Here, Whats the use of echoing inside a while loop since you have not linked with any variable ?

Comment: It is returning the correct link and the correct name of my link...

What do you mean by CPT name being Object?

Comment: @Indra Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: @NabilKadimi Yes, I am trying to loop through posts of a custom post type I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way (code below), which will show something only if:

- There is at least one **published** post **of type `object`**

```
new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'object',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
) );

while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    printf(
        '<div class="item"><a href="%s">%s</a></div>'
        , get_permalink()
        , get_the_title()
    );
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
```

### Notes:

- I don't store the WP_Query object since it will not be used
- I use  `printf()` for better readibility
- [I don't forget to add `wp_reset_query();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) which is necessary in most cases

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing like this

```
   echo '<div class="item"><a href="'.$mylink.'">'.$myTitle.'</a></div>';
```